# .htaccess redirect to a directory and retain $_GET variables?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect from `/orders/whatever/?n=4`

to:

```
/orders/?shopURL=whatever&n=4
```

I managed to redirect to the correct directory but I'm losing the passed variables.

This is my current rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w\d]+)$ /orders/?shopURL=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enforce the existence of a query string, use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  (\bn=\d+\b)
RewriteRule ^orders/([\w\d]+)/?$ /orders/?shopURL=$1&%1 [L]
```

Otherwise, you can use the following without a RewriteCond:

```
RewriteRule ^orders/([\w\d]+)/?$ /orders/?shopURL=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: except that `(n=\d*)` will also match `ban=234G`.  Use `(\bn=\d*\b)` in this case.

Comment: You could probably avoid the \b on the end since \d will only match numbers, but adding it to the front is definitely necessary. I'll update my answer to use that. (I'd never really used \b before and couldn't think of how to prevent the `ban` versus `n` situation, so thanks for pointing that out!)

Comment: Yup, most developers don't realise that the Apache regexp engine is a **full** PCRE implementation.  So all of the goodies like the meta characters, non-greedy matching, lookahead/behind assertions, \n variables all work.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `QSA` flag to `RewriteRule` will retain existing query string fields.

Answer (score 0):

Your RewriteRule seems very generic, as though it would redirect almost every page.

I'm not that great with Regular Expressions so I'll leave those to you, or someone else. But you need something at the end of the rewrite rule to catch parameters, then append it at the end of the new URL.

```
RewriteRule ^([\w\d]+)/(somethinghere)$ /orders/?shopURL=$1&$2 [L]
```